# Is a "deterministic" subset of a random subset random?

Tags: probability, random-variables, random, random-graphs

Let $S$ be some set and consider $X \subseteq S$ of size $|X|=x$ u.a.r. (among all the subsets having this size).

Now, use some properties of this set $X$ to find some subset $Y\subseteq X$ of some (variable) size $y$.

When we know want to argue about $Y$, can we argue that it is a random set, when we do not reuse the information for splitting $X$ into $X\setminus Y$ and $Y$?

MORE BACKGROUND:

Consider a "random" graph $G=(V,E)$ and choose $k$ many subsets $X_1, \dotsc, X_k$ u.a.r. with $|X_1|=|X_2|= \dotsc =|X_k|=x$, all disjoint. Now consider $X_i$. Depending on the edges from $X_1, \dotsc, X_{i-1}$ into $X_i$, we split $X_i$ into two parts $X_i \setminus Y_i$ and $Y_i$. When we now argue about edges going from $Y_i$ to $X_{i+1}, \dotsc, X_{k}$, can we say that it is the same as if we have chosen $Y_i$ u.a.r., when all edges are independent?

Comment: It depends on the exact algorithm, but in almost all cases the answer is no: the choices of the $Y$ are not uniformly distributed.
Consider that if the algorithm depends on the edges, vertices with high degree will influence the algorithm more than vertices with low degree, skewing the distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not entirely sure what you mean with the example, so maybe I just sketch a simplified algorithm that is similar to the one I aim for. 
Given $X_1, \dotsc, X_{i-1}$. If there is an edge from a vertex in $X_{i-1}$ to $x_i \in X_i$, then add $x_i to Y_i$. I see that this influences $Y_i$ in such a way that $y \in Y_i$ tends to have higher degree (and hence, it is not random). But now, if I use this set $Y_i$ only to argue about $X_{i+1}$, then this shouldn't influence the size of $Y_i$, as all the edges are "new ones". Is this correct as well?

Comment: It depends on which random graph you use. If you are using $G(n,p)$, then yes, we haven't queried the potential edges from $Y_i$ to $X_{i+1}, \ldots$ yet, so their presence is independent of the previously found information. However, in other models, say geometric random graphs, this old information *does* influence whether there are edges from $Y_i$ to $X_{i+1}, \ldots$.

Comment: Well, I use some kind of $G(n,p)$. Actually, I start with a deterministic graph $G$ (e.g. a Dirac graph with $\delta(G) \geq \frac{n}{2}$) and then take a random subgraph of it, deleting each edge independently with probability $1-p$. (So $G(n,p)$ is obtained by taking $G=K_n$). It is not exactly $G(n,p)$, but the edges I take are still independent, I hope?

Comment: The edges won't be completely independent if you start with a requirement such as $\delta(G)\ge n/2$. Consider that you have seen that $x$ is not connected to all vertices in some set $S$. Then, what is the probability that it is connected to some $y$ not in $S$? If edges were independent, this probability would be the same if you knew nothing about $x$, but this is not your case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this really helps a lot. I will have to think about it a little bit longer!